# react.js / axios - How to store csrf token in cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios, csrf-token

I'm doing a project for my class and we're required to make a secure login feature..something I haven't done before.. I'm trying to store the csrfToken in a header so it shows up as my session token in cookies but I'm not sure I'm doing it right.If anyone could help, I'd be very grateful. I know this is probably an easy fix but I've looked everywhere and haven't got it yet.

```
getToken = () => {

    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/csrf',
        timeout: 1000,
        headers: 'csrf-token'
    }).then(csrfToken => {
        console.log(csrfToken);
        this.setState({ accessGranted: true })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I'm getting a response in the console but it's not storing it in the cookies.

Comment: If I understood you correctly you need to pass the `csrfToken` each and everytime you call an api - Is it so? or storing the csrfToken in cookie is enough?

Comment: yes, how would i pass the csrfToken each and everytime i call an api?:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use react-cookies:

```
import cookie from 'react-cookies'
```

and save your cookie like this:

```
cookie.save('csrftoken', csrfToken);
```

Then you can use it whenever you want.

Comment: Okay and what is the other way? to pass the csrfToken each and everytime you call an api

Comment: You can access the token with `const token = cookie.get('csrftoken');` and then you can pass it to axios as a header? `axios.get(
    url,
    {headers: {
        "name" : "value"
      }
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
      // other code
  );`

Comment: @walkforr the specific name of the header and method of passing it would depend on the backend. Also, you may or may not want to consider `localStorage` as something where you would save your token. It's a simple as `localStorage.setItem('name', value)` and `localStorage.getItem('name')`

Comment: And here's a bit of text about localStorage vs cookies, in case you care: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies

Comment: If you want to automatically pass the header at each request you can use axios request interceptors.

Comment: Yes you can use axios interceptor to pass it in each and every time when you call the api, something like this
`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = csrftoken `

Comment: You actually should not pass a CSRF token in a cookie. That's the whole point of a CSRF token. See OWASP guide here. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html